# How to get excel sheet 1 data in excel sheet 2 using cell number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two Excel sheets and I want to fetch data from the particular cell number from `sheet1` to `sheet2`.

In `sheet2` I have two columns: the first column contain the cell number of `sheet1`; and using that cell number I want to fetch that data into the adjacent cell.

Example:

`Sheet1` : A15 contains "Hello"

`Sheet2` : column A contains cell name and number

Worked example: in `sheet2` cell `A5` contains `A15` so in `B5` I want "Hello" (i.e. the data in `A15` on `sheet1`)

Comment: without some example data, have a look at vlookup() or index() with match()...

Comment: Based on the text you have added, I think you should check out the indirect() function, as you need to build the target sheet name with the cell reference.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, but i am very new in excel and i don't have that much knowledge, I am trying to use in B5 column "=Sheet1!(Sheet2!A5)" but it's not the proper formula. please guide me in that.

Answer (score 2):

## INDIRECT

In `Sheet2`, cell `B5` use the formula:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&A5)
```

### INDIRECT Links

- [Office
  Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)
- [ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-indirect-function)
- [Contextures](https://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html)